# ISO C90 error while declaring an array and using malloc

Tags: c, sublimetext3, c99

I just learned dynamic memory allocation so i tried to test it out. I am using **sublime text 3** with the following build configuration

```
 {
"cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
 }
```

**I have included the path to gcc compiler in the path variable from the codeblocks bin folder**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin

And the C code i used to tried to run looks like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int *order=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&*(order+i));

    printf("%d",order[2]); /*just seeing whether output is properly displayed or not */

    return 0;
}
```

The error that the sublime text is showing is:

```
8:2: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
```

> I tried running my code in codeblocks and it works perfectly. so is
>   there any way by which i can run my c programs in C99 instead of C90
>   using sublime text 3 itself

Comment: add "-std=C99" to the configuration

Comment: Not related, but: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general in C.

Comment: `c90` does not allow variable declaration anywhere except immediately after a opening brace '{'.  However, that posted code has a logic flaw.  If the call to malloc() fails, then the following line, which accesses offsets from the pointer returned from malloc() will be undefined behaviour and will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *run* your programs with a given *standard* you compile them with it's rules.

The text editor has nothing to do with that. To fix the problem, replace the `-ansi` flag with `-std=c99` from this list

```
"cmd": [
        "gcc", 
        "-Wall", 
        "-std=c99",
        "-pedantic-errors",
        "$file_name", 
        "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", 
        "&&", 
        "start", 
        "cmd", 
        "/k" , 
        "$file_base_name"
]
```

To make the code clearer you can declare variables only at the begining of a block, that's what the error is about. In [c90](/questions/tagged/c90) it was forbidden to mix *declarations* with code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int *order
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return -1;
    order = malloc(sizeof(*order) * n);
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        scanf("%d", order + i); // Please check the return value here too/
    printf("%d", order[2]); // This might invoke UB because you ignored
                            // `scanf()'s return value in the loop.
    return 0;
}
```

So the declaration

```
int *order = ...
```

was causing the error, moving it to the begining of the block will solve it.

Also, note that you don't need to cast `malloc()`'s return value to the target pointer type and in general `void *` is automatically converted to the target pointer type.

Comment: @M.M I didn't see that! Wow!

Answer (score 1):

> so is there any way by which i can run my c programs in C99 instead of C90 using sublime text 3 itself

Set the flag `-std=c99`.